# How tf.transpose works in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matplotlib, tensorflow

```
tf.transpose(a, perm=None, name='transpose')
```

transposes a. It permutes the dimensions according to perm. So if I am using this matrix to transform:

```
import tensorflow as tt
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
import numpy as bb
ab=([[[1,2,3],[6,5,4]],[[4,5,6],[3,6,3]]])
v=bb.array(ab)
fg=tt.transpose(v)
print(v)

with tt.Session() as df:
    print("\n New tranformed matrix is: \n\n{}".format(df.run(fg)))
```

Result is :

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [6 5 4]]

 [[4 5 6]
  [3 6 3]]]

 New tranformed matrix is: 

[[[1 4]
  [6 3]]

 [[2 5]
  [5 6]]

 [[3 6]
  [4 3]]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

now if i use perm argument then :

```
import tensorflow as tt
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
import numpy as bb
ab=([[[1,2,3],[6,5,4]],[[4,5,6],[3,6,3]]])
v=bb.array(ab)
fg=tt.transpose(v,perm=[0,2,1])
print(v)

with tt.Session() as df:
    print("\n New tranformed matrix is: \n\n{}".format(df.run(fg)))
```

Result is :

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [6 5 4]]

 [[4 5 6]
  [3 6 3]]]

 New tranformed matrix is: 

[[[1 6]
  [2 5]
  [3 4]]

 [[4 3]
  [5 6]
  [6 3]]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Due to this, I am confused and I have two questions :

- Whenever I want to transpose a matrix I have to give perm[0,2,1] as
  default ?
- What is 0,2,1 here ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) documentation, we find that `transpose` takes the argument

> `axes` : *list of ints, optional*
> By default, reverse the dimensions, otherwise permute the axes according to the values given.

So the default call to `transpose` translates into `np.transpose(a, axes=[1,0])` for the 2D case, or `np.transpose(a, axes=[2,1,0])`.

The operation you want to have here, is one that leaves the "depth" dimension unchanged. Therefore in the axes argument, the depth axes, which is the `0`th axes, needs to stay unchanged. The axes `1` and `2` (where 1 is the vertical axis), need to change positions. So you change the axes order from the initial `[0,1,2]` to `[0,2,1]` (`[stays the same, changes with other, changes with other]`).

In tensorflow, they have for some reason renamed `axes` to `perm`. The argument from above stays the same.

#### images

Concerning images, they differ from the arrays in the question.  Images normally have their x and y stored in the first two dimensions and the channel in the last, `[y,x,channel]`.

In order to "transpose" an image in the sense of a 2D transposition, where horizontal and vertical axes are exchanged, you would need to use

```
np.transpose(a, axes=[1,0,2])
```

(channel stays the same, x and y are exchanged).

[image]

Comment: so you mean the initial axes of every image in tensorflow is [0,1,2] ?
where 1 is the vertical then what are 0 and 2 ? 2 is horizontal ?
now i build a program which rotate the image so if i am using [1,0,2] then image is rotating otherwise if i use other combinations its not rotating.

Comment: or 2 is 2d dimension and 0 is horizontal and 1 is vertical in [0,1,2] ?

Comment: For an image 0 is vertical, 1 is horizontal. See updated answer.